# 4 digit year between year x and year y - javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex in javascript that will check that the input is 4 digit long and between 2 valid years.

for example: between 1930 - 2012
 is it possible?

Comment: Yes, what have you tried?

Comment: While this is possible with a regular expression, its much easier to use: `function isValidYear (yearStr) { var year = parseInt(yearStr, 10); return year >= 1930 && year <= 2012; }`

Comment: i am going to check also with js Date. but for initial check i need it in regex also

Answer (score 3):

Ref from http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range

```
First, break into equal length ranges:
  1930 - 2012

Second, break into ranges that yield simple regexes:
  1930 - 1999
  2000 - 2009
  2010 - 2012

Turn each range into a regex:
  19[3-9][0-9]
  200[0-9]
  201[0-2]

Collapse adjacent powers of 10:
  19[3-9][0-9]
  200[0-9]
  201[0-2]

Combining the regexes above yields:
  (19[3-9][0-9]|200[0-9]|201[0-2])

Next we'll try factoring out common prefixes using a tree:
Parse into tree based on regex prefixes:
  . 1 9 [3-9] [0-9]
    2 0 0 +----
      + 1 [0-2]

Turning the parse tree into a regex yields:
  (19[3-9][0-9]|20(0[0-9]|1[0-2]))

We choose the shorter one as our result.

\b(19[3-9][0-9]|200[0-9]|201[0-2])\b
```

Comment: Like npinti's suggestion, this fails to _"check that the input is 4 digit long"_.

Comment: `/\b(19[3-9][0-9]|200[0-9]|201[0-2])\b/.test('2012 2020')    // true`

Comment: `/\b(19[3-9][0-9]|200[0-9]|201[0-2])\b/.test('2012 bananas')  // true`

Comment: The link provided requires authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like so: `\b(19[3-9][0-9]|200[0-9]|201[0-2])\b` (taken from [here](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range)). That being said, you should use *numerical operators* when dealing with numbers. Doing this with regular expressions can get very messy very fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(19[3-9]\d|20(0\d|1[0-2]))$/
```